# What fuse to use for a AC/DC buck converter

Tags: fuses

I want to make this [8 channel DMX Splitter](http://www.chameleon.rs/e035020.pdf). Instead of the transformers I will use 9 [AC/DC Buck Converters, 5V/3.5W](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1KBxCSFXXXXbLXVXXq6xXFXXXn/5V-700mA-3-5W-AC-DC-Precision-Buck-Converter-AC-220v-to-5v-DC-step-down.jpg). According to the explanation 1.5W is enough so that should be ok.

The description also shows a slow blow 0.1A fuse to be used. However, I checked that these are relatively expansive, so I wonder if I can use e.g. a 0.25A or 0.5A fast blow fuse. I never used a fuse before, so I'm not sure if this could cause a problem (like sometimes for resistors/capacitors it also doesn't matter much, as long as the value is high/low enough). Or is a fuse not needed anyway because a buck converter has already safety within?

Comment: The idea of a fuse is to mitigate the consequences of some type of fault that leads to over-current. Often, the fuse is chosen based on the wire diameter. The idea is that if the current is too high for the wire, and the wire might get so hot that it can cause a fire, the fuse will blow. When fusing electronics, you have to have some idea of what fault might occur before you can really decide on a fuse. The fuse will not blow until after the fault occurs. So don't think that the fuse is somehow protecting the electronics. It is protecting the user of the electronics from fire.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you very much, I thought it was too for protecting the electronics inside. I will calculate the wire sizei I need but for 1.5W (per converter) I don't need thick wires, so I will than use the fuse that 'fits' the cable and assume a Fast blow is good enough.